# C# code returning weird numbers when converting from int to String

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2013, tostring

I've created a Time class that keeps track of hours, minutes, and am/pm.
For some reason, when I try to out text in a label and I try to convert my integers to Strings, I get very weird results.  For example, when the label should show the number `12`, it shows `-35791382` instead.  I believe this has something to do with the `toString()` method but I can't be sure.  Anyone know why this is happening?  I've tried both `.toString()` and `Convert.ToString()`.

```
protected void btngo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int hours = Convert.ToInt16(ddl2.Text);
    int minutes = Convert.ToInt16(ddl3.Text);
    bool am;
    if (ddl4.Text == "AM")
    {
        am = true;
    }
    else
    {
        am = false;
    }
    Time start = new Time(hours, minutes, am);
    Time t1 = start;
    if (ddl1.Text == "What time do you need to wake up?")
    {
        t1.hours -= 1;
        t1.minutes -= 30;
        t1.Clean();
    }
    lbl3.Text = t1.hours.ToString() + ":" + Convert.ToString(t1.minutes) + " " + Convert.ToString(t1.am);
}




public class Time
{
    public int hours;
    public int minutes;
    public bool am;

    public Time(int hours, int minutes, bool am)
    {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.am = am;
    }

    public void Clean(){
        while (this.minutes > 59)
        {
            this.hours += 1;
            this.minutes -= 60;
            if (this.hours > 12)
            {
                if (this.am == true)
                {
                    this.am = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.am = true;
                }
                this.hours -= 12;
            }
        }
        while (this.minutes < 0)
        {
            this.hours -= 1;
            this.minutes -= 60;
        }
        if (this.hours < 1)
        {
            if (this.am == true)
            {
                this.am = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.am = true;
            }
            this.hours += 12;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is `Time` class/structure definition?

Comment: have you used the debugger to step thru the code.. also you don't need the else portion of your AM check initialize the bool am = false then it ddl4.Text  == "AM"  then if will assign to true else the value will  remain false ...do you know how to use the debugger...? also look up how to use the string.Format function to assign values to lbl3.Text for better readability

Comment: Time is not a native .NET class, so I assume you've created this to represent time only. Can you post the code for this too.

Comment: Here is my Time class definition.  I am not sure how to use the debugger, how could I do that?  And thanks I'll edit the AM boolean

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Note that for string conversion issues, a console program will suffice. In any case, the code example should use hard-coded literals for initialization rather than relying on user input, to ensure that the results are 100% reproducible.

Comment: @jbart12 You use the debugger by setting breakpoints in your code and examining the state of call stack once you hit one. You'll need to look for tutorials; from a cursory search I found this page which might be a good place to start: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block will throw an overflow exception if it is ever entered:

```
    while (this.minutes < 0)
    {
        this.hours -= 1;
        this.minutes -= 60;
    }
```

...as minutes will continue decrementing by 60 forever. Are you burying an exception somewhere that isn't shown in this sample? I suspect an exception is being thrown when the minimum allowed value of Int16 is exceeded (-32768).

Comment: Thanks for the help, you are correct.  The issue was with this.minutes -= 60 when it should have been += 60

Comment: No probs. Can you mark the answer accepted if that sorted it for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It may not explain everything, but at least this:

```
while (this.minutes < 0)
{
    this.hours -= 1;
    this.minutes -= 60;
}
```

is clearly wrong. I assume you wanted to do

```
    this.minutes += 60;
```

Trying to correct the rest of your logic:

```
if (this.minutes > 59)
{
    while (this.minutes > 59)
    {
       this.hours += 1;
       this.minutes -= 60;
    }
}
else if (this.minutes < 0)
{
    while (this.minutes < 0)
    {
       this.hours -= 1;
       this.minutes += 60;
    }
}
if (this.hours <= 0)
{
    this.hours += 12;
    this.am = !this.am;
}
else if (this.hours > 12)
{
    this.hours -= 12;
    this.am = !this.am;
}
```

Comment: This fixed it.  Nice catch and thank you for your help.  Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: @jbart12 if answer or another answer solved your problem, please accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)